# How to deploy Node JS application on GoDaddy VPS using cPanel ? Step by step procedure will be highly appreciated

Tags: node.js, deployment, server, vps, godaddy-api

I have developed a node js application using MQTT protocol and it is running well on my local machine. I have purchased GoDaddy Grow plan of VPS for cloud hosting. Server OS is CentOS 7 and my local machine has Windows 10. I have to deploy my node js application on VPS so that it will keep running continuously. I have never done deployment before.

I have downloaded Putty and accessed CentOS 7. I have also installed mosquitto broker, mongoDB and NodeJS on server using Putty terminal. Now I want to deploy my code on VPS(CentOS 7) and run over there. I have also tried to do it using cPanel but since I am new to this area, I need procedure about how it is done.

I want my Node JS application to be hosted on VPS(CentOS 7) and running there. I am not able to do that. I don't even find the extact procedure about doing the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cPanel offers a detailed "how to do" guide https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+a+Node.js+Application